# JOIN by part of two column names

Tags: mysql, join, query, self-join

Consider a table with the structure of

```
id            col1
WqDs.first
WqDs.second
eeRT.first
eeRT.second
```

How can I `JOIN` the table to itself using the first part of the id

```
SELECT idxx, a.col1 AS First, b.col1 AS Second
FROM table1 a JOIN table1 b ON ....

idxx(temporary)    First     Second
WqDs
eeRT
```

I tried `LIKE` but it works when an id exists in the id of another row. I thought to trim the first id of the first row and then find it in the second row, but there should be an easier way.

Comment: Instead of having to parse `id`, make it 2 columns and use both columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locate()` to get the position of `.` and then `left()` to get the text left of it.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t11
            INNER JOIN table1 t12
                       ON left(t12.id, locate('.', t12.id) - 1) = left(t11.id, locate('.', t11.id) - 1);
```